# Clicking exit button should remove player

Tags: javascript

What I want to occur in the code is for the exit button to remove a single player.

Something would need to be added to the javascript for that to occur.

Here is a demo code of it working in here: https://jsfiddle.net/ubrch3aq/

I provided a code example of it working below.

The reason why the javascript is so big in the demo code is because it's meant to handle many players, not just one.

First click on the blue play button, then click on the exit button and you can see the player is removed.

Here is the code I am working on: https://jsfiddle.net/shqz5tkm/

That is a code where only a single player is being used.

How would I replicate how it is done in the code I am working on?

Is there a way to have it do the same thing, maybe set up in a similar or different way, but does the same thing? Removes player.

```
const manageUI = (function makeManageUI() {

  function exitClickHandler() {
   
  }

  function addClickToExit(exitButtons) {
    exitButtons.forEach(function addExitButtonHandler(exitButtons) {
      exitButtons.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addExitHandlers(callback) {
    const resetVideo = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    resetVideo.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
      video.addEventListener("click", callback);
    });
  }

  function init() {
    findPlayers();
    const exitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    addClickToExit(exitButtons);
  }

  return {
    addExitHandlers,
    getWrapper,
    init
  };
}());
```

```
function removePlayer(wrapper) {
    wrapper.player.destroy();
    delete wrapper.player;
    console.log("removePlayer");
  }

  function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
    const el = evt.target;
    const container = el.closest(".container");
    const wrapper = container.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
    wrapper.forEach(function(wrapper) {
      if (wrapper.player) {
        return removePlayer(wrapper);
      }
    });
  }
```

`manageUI.addExitHandlers(managePlayer.removePlayerHandler);`

Clicking exit button should remove player

Code I am working on, clicking on the exit button does nothing. https://jsfiddle.net/shqz5tkm/

```js
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function openCurtain(cover) {
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
    return curtain;
  }

  function showVideo(curtain) {
    const thewrap = curtain.parentElement.querySelector(".wrap");
    show(thewrap);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    const curtain = openCurtain(cover);
    showVideo(curtain);
    cover.dispatchEvent(new Event("afterClick"));
  }

  function init(callback) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(".play");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    cover.addEventListener("afterClick", callback);
  }

  return {
    init
  };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  let playlist;
  let player;

  function loadIframeScript() {
    const tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  }

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const cover = document.querySelector(".play");
    const wrapper = cover.parentElement;
    const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
    addPlayer(frameContainer, playlist);
  }

  function shufflePlaylist(player) {
    player.setShuffle(true);
    player.playVideoAt(0);
    player.stopVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
    shufflePlaylist(player);
  }

  function createPlaylist(videoIds) {
    return videoIds.join();
  }

  function createOptions(videoIds) {
    const options = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      width: 640
    };
    options.playerVars = {
      autoplay: 0,
      cc_load_policy: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      rel: 0
    };
    options.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };

    options.playerVars.loop = 1;
    options.playerVars.playlist = createPlaylist(videoIds);
    return options;
  }

  function createVideoOptions(ids) {
    const options = createOptions(ids);
    return options;
  }

  function addPlayer(video, ids) {
    const options = createVideoOptions(ids);
    player = new YT.Player(video, options);
    return player;
  }

  function play() {
    if (player && player.playVideo) {
      player.playVideo();
    }
  }

  function init(videoIds) {
    player = null;
    loadIframeScript();
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
    playlist = videoIds;
    return play;
  }

  return {
    init,
    play
  };
}());

manageCover.init(videoPlayer.init([
  "0dgNc5S8cLI",

]));
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {

}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 255px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
}


.video-one {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

iframe {
  user-select: none;
}

.play {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 9px solid;
  z-index: 1;
  background: transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #000000b3);
  border-color: blue;
  animation: fadeInPlay 2s ease-in 2s forwards;
  animation-delay: 10s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.play::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 27px solid;
  transform: translateX(4px);
  border-left-color: blue;
}

.play:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(20, 179, 33, 0.5);
}

.play:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(111, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

.exit::before,
.exit::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 47px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.exit::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="curtain">
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap hide">
                <div class="video video-frame" data-id=""></div>
            </div>

            <div class="video-one"></div>

        </div>
   <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>

    </div>
    <button class="play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
</div>
```

**Demo Code**, clicking on the exit button removes player. https://jsfiddle.net/ubrch3aq/

First click on the blue play button, then click on the exit button and you can see the player is removed.

```js
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {

  function showCover(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCover(cover);
    const curtain = evt.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function init(selectors) {
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init
  };
}());

const manageUI = (function makeManageUI() {
  const body = document.body;

  const players = [];

  function findPlayers() {
    const allCovers = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");
    const allWrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
    allCovers.forEach(function addToPlayers(cover, index) {
      players.push({
        "cover": cover,
        "wrapper": allWrappers[index]
      });
    });
  }

  // inline arrow function, direct return
  function getWrapper(cover) {
    const index = players.findIndex(
      (player) => player.cover === cover
    );
    return players[index].wrapper;
  }



  function exitClickHandler() {
   
  }

  function addClickToExit(exitButtons) {
    exitButtons.forEach(function addExitButtonHandler(exitButtons) {
      exitButtons.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addExitHandlers(callback) {
    const resetVideo = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    resetVideo.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
      video.addEventListener("click", callback);
    });
  }

  function init() {
    findPlayers();
    const exitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    addClickToExit(exitButtons);
  }

  return {
    addExitHandlers,
    getWrapper,
    init
  };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {

  let player;

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    return player;
  }


  function addPlayer(video, playerOptions) {
    playerOptions.videoId = playerOptions.videoId || video.dataset.id;
    playerOptions.events = playerOptions.events || {};
    playerOptions.events.onReady = onPlayerReady;
    playerOptions.events.onStateChange = onPlayerStateChange;

    const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
    return player;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {

  const playerVars = {
    autoplay: 0,
    controls: 1,
    disablekb: 1,
    fs: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3
  };

  const defaults = {
    height: 360,
    host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
    playerVars,
    width: 640
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function combinePlayerOptions(opts1 = {}, opts2 = {}) {
    const combined = Object.assign({}, opts1, opts2);
    Object.keys(opts1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
      if (typeof opts1[prop] === "object") {
        combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, opts1[prop], opts2[prop]);
      }
    });
    return combined;
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, playerOptions = {}) {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    const options = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, playerOptions);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, options);
  }

  function playerAdder(wrapper, playerOptions) {
    return function addPlayerCallback() {
      initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    };
  }

  function removePlayer(wrapper) {
    wrapper.player.destroy();
    delete wrapper.player;
    console.log("removePlayer");
  }

  function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
    const el = evt.target;
    const container = el.closest(".container");
    const wrapper = container.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
    wrapper.forEach(function(wrapper) {
      if (wrapper.player) {
        return removePlayer(wrapper);
      }
    });
  }

  function initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions) {
    show(wrapper);
    const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    wrapper.player = player;
  }

  return {
    adder: playerAdder,
    removePlayerHandler
  };
}());

const players = (function coverUIPlayerFacade() {

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerOptions) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    const wrapper = manageUI.getWrapper(cover);
    const callback = managePlayer.adder(wrapper, playerOptions);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, callback);
  }

  function init() {
    manageCover.init({
      container: ".container",
      playButton: ".cover"
    });

    manageUI.init({});
    manageUI.addExitHandlers(managePlayer.removePlayerHandler);
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer,
    init
  };
}());

players.init();

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  players.add(".playa", {
    playerVars: {
      loop: 1,
      playlist: "djV11Xbc914"
    }
  });

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {

}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain {
  margin: auto auto 40px;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
}

.embed-youtube iframe,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play::before {
  position: absolute;
}

.embed-youtube iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 9px solid blue;
  background: transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #000000b3);
  z-index: 1;
}

.embed-youtube-play::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 27px solid blue;
  transform: translateX(4px);
}

.embed-youtube-play:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.embed-youtube-play:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.embed-youtube.active .embed-youtube-play {
  display: none;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;*/
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

@keyframes fadeInExit {
  99% {
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  100% {
    pointer-events: initial;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.exit::before,
.exit::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 47px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.exit::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <!-- 1. Video Wrapper Container -->
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube ">
        <div class="video embed-youtube">
        </div>
        <!-- 2. The preview button that will contain the Play icon -->
        <button class="playa cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
     <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
  </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This includes a brand new **minimalistic** code setup along with listing the relevant packages and their versions.

Comment: So, basically, you want a wrapper container box which has few buttons like "Play" and "Close" ? And when you click "Play", it should start playing the youtube video?

Comment: Yea. That is on click of the "Exit" button. I was trying to understand your project to help you create a minimal example.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Every current browser contains good debugging capabilities for JS code